# Ticker feeds in Chat

Tags: discussion, feature-request, chat, feed

The ticker feeds in chat are interesting, but also annoying.  One feature that would make them very nice is a fade feature, where they fade away after displaying for N seconds (perhaps even user adjustable).  As an example of this, I didn't clear my ticker for a while, and this is what I got:

[image: Ticker feed]

Comment: I've actually gone to lunch and come back to have the ticker filling my entire screen. Perhaps it could be set up to only allow X number of feed items at a time?

Comment: Unless it's user adjustable or disableable, this is a bad idea IMO. The feed exists to show you things you might have missed, right? Having them disappear before you see them defeats the purpose.

Comment: @Geobits how about adjustable by the room owner? That seems like the more likely implementation considering only room owners can adjust feeds currently.

Comment: @RubberDuck Better, but considering the OP and I are often in the same chat room, I doubt it would satisfy everyone ;) Besides, this feels more like a user-control to me, like notification toggling.

Comment: In the VBA room, it is a feed of questions tagged VBA coming from SO.

Comment: @Geobits you hit the nail on the head: it *should* (probably) be by-user, but it's by-room.

Comment: Is that windows 10?

Comment: @EthanBierlein looks like it to me :)

Comment: Yep, it is Windows 10.

Comment: I think the whole thing is horrendous. Just have the things posted by feeds.

Comment: @bjb568 that's not real practical for high volume feeds like those that come from SO. It floods chat. The ticker is nice for that.

Comment: Feed ticker? Nice? What is this, a difference in oppinion‽

Comment: I agree that fading it out after time would somewhat defeat the purpose of catching up with missed posts so why don't we just make it a user setting? Let me decide what I want to see.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I like the idea of having items disappear after *N* seconds. This would have to be adjusted for different sites, of course - after all, Stack Overflow has a much higher question rate than, say, Meta Stack Exchange - but that could be done by room owners or mods, or individual users, if personalization is possible.

I have a slightly different suggestion: **Have an item disappear when *N* items appear that are newer than it.** This would be like the "Newest" tab on the Questions page of each Stack Exchange site. This means that there would be an absolute maximum amount of items in the feed at all times, and so only a limited amount of space would be taken up. In the "*N* seconds" system, you could have varying amounts of items, each for a given time. This could clog up the screen. Having *N* items makes sure that doesn't happen.

It does mean that each item may have a shorter moment of glory, but that's better than completely messing up the screen, right?

For sites with low question rates - where it may take a full day for *N* items to appear - then perhaps there could be a set amount of time built in, such that each item won't end up staying for too long. On sites like that, though, there isn't much risk of the screen getting clogged up, so perhaps a change isn't necessary at all there.

Answer (score 0):

I think we should instead make the ticker feeds semi-transparent and become full opacity on hover, since when you're reading the transcript having slightly opaque tickers aren't as disturbing, and you can always just clear it if they become a problem. See live example with CSS in Stack Snippet:

```css
#feed-ticker {opacity: 0.3 !important;}
#feed-ticker:hover {opacity: 1 !important;}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//cdn-chat.sstatic.net/chat/css/chat.stackoverflow.com.css?v=4b02a893c004"><div id="feed-ticker"><div id="feed-ticker-icon"><img src="//cdn-chat.sstatic.net/chat/Img/feed-icon128.png?v=7fa832f0199b"></div><div id="dismiss-ticker">dismiss</div><h2><a href="/rooms/info/20575/alpha-centauri?tab=feeds">New feed items</a></h2><div id="ticker-items"><div class="ticker-item"><img src="//cdn.sstatic.net/stackoverflow/img/apple-touch-icon.png" width="16" height="16" title="http://stackoverflow.com/feeds/tag?tagnames=java"><a href="//stackoverflow.com/questions/30634874/android-application-not-opening-from-phone-icon-but-opens-from-playstore" style="color: #0077CC;">Android Application Not opening from phone Icon but opens from playstore</a></div><div class="ticker-item"><img src="//cdn.sstatic.net/stackoverflow/img/apple-touch-icon.png" width="16" height="16" title="http://stackoverflow.com/feeds/tag?tagnames=java"><a href="//stackoverflow.com/questions/30634872/concurrentmodificationexception-issue-when-running-two-thread" style="color: #0077CC;">ConcurrentModificationException Issue When Running Two Thread</a></div><div class="ticker-item"><img src="//cdn.sstatic.net/stackoverflow/img/apple-touch-icon.png" width="16" height="16" title="http://stackoverflow.com/feeds/tag?tagnames=java"><a href="//stackoverflow.com/questions/30634859/what-is-hashcode-in-java-and-how-it-will-find" style="color: #0077CC;">What is Hashcode in java and How it will find..?</a></div><div class="ticker-item"><img src="//cdn.sstatic.net/stackoverflow/img/apple-touch-icon.png" width="16" height="16" title="http://stackoverflow.com/feeds/tag?tagnames=java"><a href="//stackoverflow.com/questions/30634856/how-to-cluster-ehcache-used-as-2nd-level-cache-for-hibernate" style="color: #0077CC;">How to cluster Ehcache used as 2nd level cache for Hibernate</a></div><div class="ticker-item"><img src="//cdn.sstatic.net/stackoverflow/img/apple-touch-icon.png" width="16" height="16" title="http://stackoverflow.com/feeds/tag?tagnames=java"><a href="//stackoverflow.com/questions/30634849/round-off-a-double-number-to-a-specied-pattern" style="color: #0077CC;">round off a double number to a specied pattern</a></div></div></div>
```

Comment: Are you going to make transparent text?  I will still have to close the things regularly.